Stimulus controller not running under Safari
The following library was installed in an application, invoking two specific controllers.
import {
  PasswordConfirmController,
  PasswordPeekController,
} from "stimulus-library";
application.register("password-confirm", PasswordConfirmController);
application.register("password-peek", PasswordPeekController);

The HTML renders as:
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
  <div class="cell small-9">
    password
    <input autocomplete="current-password" data-password-peek-target="password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
  </div>
  <div class="cell small-3">
    <br>
    <a data-action="password-peek#toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i> / <i class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

With Firefox, Opera and Thorium, the controller fires as expected.  With Safari (Version 15.4 (17613.1.17.1.6), the toggle does not fire (the expected 'peek' at the password is not shown).
How can one determine which version of Safari would support these stimulus controllers?

Please add exactly how safari "does not work" to the question.

The question was updated.  It is my suspicion that it is a browser versioning issue (possibly importmaps?) but that remains a suspicion... and by posing the suspicion, the answer revealed itself.

importmap-rails v2 has dropped the shim for browsers not supporting importmaps, you might want to add it back https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims

The answer may be due to support for import maps.  At least this ressource confirms the safari version quoted is below the acceptable threshold.
